# SUMPRODUCT: calculating multiple sheets

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Purpose:
I have 13 tabs. Tab one consolidates data from other sheets using fairly simple formulas. I am attempting to create a formula that will provide a total sum from all 12 sheets by identifying which "team" the charge belongs to. The sheets look similar to the following:

```
Amount  Team
$52.00  Team Bob
$2.52   Team Gene
```

I will need the total for each "team" to be tallied on the beginning summary page.

This is the formula I built.

**=SUMPRODUCT(--('January 14'!H3:H31="Team Bob"),'January 14'!G3:G31)**+('February 14'!H3:H31="Team Gene"),'February 14'!G3:*G31*)

The first half works (in bold), but when I try to add the formula to pull from the next tab it highlights "G31" and does not make recommendations on how to repair. How do I add additional tabs so that I have the data from January added with all other months?

Comment: try this one: `=SUMPRODUCT(--('January 14'!H3:H31="Team Bob"),'January 14'!G3:G31)+SUMPRODUCT(--('February 14'!H3:H31="Team Gene"),'February 14'!G3:G31)`

Answer (score 0):

A more generic way of doing this is using the =INDIRECT function - which lets you construct your reference by giving it the sheet name/range. Here's an example:

https://spreadgit.com/bjoern/monthly-tabs-sum.xlsx/sheets/Summary